# Xamarin.Essentials:Preferences Isn't Storing Stepper Value

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

In my application, I have multiple steppers with corresponding entries to display each stepper's current value. I am attempting to use Xamarin.Essentials:Preferences to save this value for later use when the app is reopened, but Preferences doesn't appear to be saving the stepper value and/or inputting said value when the Application is being reopened.

Here is one example of the xaml...

```
          <Grid x:Name="PurchasePriceGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".6*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Text="Purchase Price" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="0,0,25,0" Scale="1.2" TranslationX="15" 
                   Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" />
                <customentry:MyEntry x:Name="PurchasePriceEntry" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference PurchasePriceStepper}, Path=Value, FallbackValue=0}"
                                 TextColor="DarkSlateGray" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Ivory" TranslationX="10"
                                 Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="End" MaxLength="5"
                                 TextChanged="PurchasePriceEntry_Completed" />
                <Stepper x:Name="PurchasePriceStepper" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  Scale=".7" TranslationX="3"
                     Maximum="5" Minimum=".01" Increment=".01" Value="{Binding PurchasePriceStepperValue}" />
            </Grid>
```

Here is the C#...

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

...

    public double PurchasePriceStepperValue
    {
        get => Preferences.Get(nameof(PurchasePriceStepperValue), 1.75);
        set
        {
            Preferences.Set(nameof(PurchasePriceStepperValue), value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PurchasePriceStepperValue));
        }
    }
```

And here is the Android MainActivity.cs...

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

...

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

I am new to programming and have spent multiple hours trying multiple different things to try to figure out why Xamarin.Essentials:Preferences isn't saving/inputting the steppers value into the entry. I have implemented the NuGet package in all projects. I can try to give more code if it would help.

Comment: `Preferences Isn't Working. What am I doing Wrong?` isn't a technical description of a problem nor an appropriate way to ask a question in stackoverflow, Please be more specific about the problem you have, what you expect to happen, what is happening and any errors that are being thrown

Comment: I've edited to try to make it a little clearer and it isn't throwing any errors.

Comment: What's the default value of Stepper you see when you reopen your app,0.01 or 1.75?

Comment: The default value when I reopen the app is: 0.01 which is the minimum value set in the xaml file for the steppers value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The default value when you reopen the app is: 0.01** means your binding is not working.

I use the same code in `Xaml` and `MainActivity.cs` as yours and use the code behind like below codes:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PurchasePriceModel model = new PurchasePriceModel();

        BindingContext = model;
    }
}


class PurchasePriceModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public double PurchasePriceStepperValue
    {
        get => Preferences.Get(nameof(PurchasePriceStepperValue), 1.75);
        set
        {
            Preferences.Set(nameof(PurchasePriceStepperValue), value);
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(PurchasePriceStepperValue)));
        }
    }

    public PurchasePriceModel()
    {

    }

}
```

It works on my side.Check your `BindingContext` and codes in `Model`.